# JASlidingpanels storyboard example root view controller error

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am trying to implement the JASliding panels by using story boards i have created a left and center panel as well as a subclass for the jaslider class

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
@interface RootViewController ()
@end
@implementation RootViewController
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
[self setLeftPanel:[self.storyboard
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftViewController"]];
[self setCenterPanel:[self.storyboard
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerViewController"]];
[self setRightPanel:nil];
}
@end
```

i only want to use the left and center panels.
 i keep getting this in the output

> JASidePanelSB[31404:c07] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

I have created the viewers in the storyboard with the identifiers and the viewer ascociated with the RootViewController is the initial view with the arrow on the left side.

is there something else that i am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. Since I started the project as an empty application, XCode added the code to alloc a new UIWindow object that was interfering and giving the error. If anyone else wonders, make sure this code isn't in the `didFinishLoadingWithOptions` method

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lie in the method. You are calling `awakeFromNib` but are using storyboards. Try putting your code in like this:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
@interface RootViewController ()
@end
@implementation RootViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self setLeftPanel:[self.storyboard
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftViewController"]];
    [self setCenterPanel:[self.storyboard
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerViewController"]];
    [self setRightPanel:nil];

    [self.sidePanelController showCenterPanelAnimated:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
@end
```

Notice that I am using `viewDidLoad` and not `awakeFromNib` because `awakeFromNib` is called when the controller itself is unarchived from a nib. `viewDidLoad` is called when the view is created/unarchived.

You don't got no nibs.

Comment: no i still get the same Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch output message. what i have is the instructions on the site [link](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels#example-2-storyboards)

Comment: Did you do this? "2. Make sure to #import "JASidePanelController.h" in MySidePanelController.h". I can't see if you did or not.

Comment: well RootViewController is a subclass of JASidePanelController so it gets imported automatically i  also checked that it was being imported.

Comment: @XavierSerrano Wait, is that your entire .m file? Why don't you make your RootViewController a subclass of UIViewController, import the appropriate files, and replace the `viewDidLoad` method in the UIViewController with the code I showed above?